# Install a specific version of an older package by adding an old mirror

Tags: apt, package-management, gcc

I'm attempting to install a specific version of gcc to Ubuntu 18.04.

By default the version of Ubuntu at the time of this writing is `18.04.5`. Installing it  with `sudo apt-get install gcc-7` results in the following:

```
user@server:~$ gcc-7 -v
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 
user@server:~$ sudo apt-cache policy gcc-7
gcc-7:
  Installed: 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
  Candidate: 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
  Version table:
 *** 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 500
        500 http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     7.3.0-16ubuntu3 500
        500 http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Apt recognizes two versions and has installed the `7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04` one.
I need the version `7.4.0`.

I have found a [package mirror](https://mirror.squ.edu.om/ubuntuarchive/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-7/) which has the required package version (`gcc-7-multilib_7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb`) and did the following:

```
# Add "deb https://mirror.squ.edu.om/ubuntuarchive/ubuntu bionic main restricted multiverse universe" to /etc/apt/sources.list
user@server:~$ sudo apt-get update
user@server:~$ sudo apt-cache policy gcc-7
gcc-7:
  Installed: 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
  Candidate: 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
  Version table:
 *** 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 500
        500 http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     7.3.0-16ubuntu3 500
        500 http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 https://mirror.squ.edu.om/ubuntuarchive/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

However this only added a new mirror to the `7.3.0-16ubuntu3`. It didn't introduce the version `7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04` which exists as a package in the mirrors. I expected to see the new versions available.

Am looking for an explanation for this behavior and ways to add the `7.4.0` version?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

1. Look at `apt changelog gcc-7-multilib` to see which older releases of Ubuntu include version 7.4.0. This avoids a lot of mucking about with broken dependencies. Here's the edited  list:

```
    gcc-7 (7.5.0-1ubuntu1) focal
    gcc-7 (7.4.0-15ubuntu1) focal

    gcc-7 (7.4.0-14ubuntu2) eoan
    gcc-7 (7.4.0-14ubuntu1) eoan
    gcc-7 (7.4.0-12ubuntu2) eoan
    gcc-7 (7.4.0-11ubuntu1) eoan
    gcc-7 (7.4.0-10ubuntu2) eoan
    gcc-7 (7.4.0-9ubuntu1) eoan

    gcc-7 (7.4.0-8ubuntu1) disco
    gcc-7 (7.4.0-7ubuntu1) disco
    gcc-7 (7.4.0-6ubuntu1) disco
    gcc-7 (7.4.0-5ubuntu1) disco
    gcc-7 (7.4.0-4ubuntu1) disco
    gcc-7 (7.4.0-3ubuntu2) disco
    gcc-7 (7.4.0-3ubuntu1) disco
    gcc-7 (7.4.0-2ubuntu1) disco
    gcc-7 (7.4.0-1ubuntu1) disco
    gcc-7 (7.3.0-31ubuntu1) disco
```

2. You can see that both 19.04 (Disco) and 19.10 (Eoan) shipped with the version you want.

   - **Note**: Both releases are past End of Life. Neither receives security patches, and neither is supported here at AskUbuntu anymore.
3. Unsupported releases of Ubuntu are available at https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ . If you decide to use an old release for a specific purpose, run it in a VM and be sensible about its access to your network.